# What is the difference between Vec<struct> and &[struct]?

Tags: vector, data-structures, rust

I often find myself getting an error like this:

```
mismatched types: expected `collections::vec::Vec<u8>`, found `&[u8]` (expected struct collections::vec::Vec, found &-ptr)
```

As far as I know, one is mutable and one isn't but I've no idea how to go between the types, i.e. take a `&[u8]` and make it a `Vec<u8>` or vice versa.

What's the different between them? Is it the same as `String` and `&str`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is it the same as `String` and `&str`?

Yes. A `Vec<T>` is the owned variant of a `&[T]`. `&[T]` is a *reference* to a set of `T`s laid out sequentially in memory (a.k.a. a *slice*). It represents a pointer to the beginning of the items and the number of items. A reference refers to something that you don't own, so the set of actions you can do with it are limited. There is a mutable variant (`&mut [T]`), which allows you to mutate the items in the slice. You can't change how many are in the slice though. Said another way, you can't mutate the slice itself.

> take a `&[u8]` and make it a `Vec`

For *this specific case*:

```
let s: &[u8]; // Set this somewhere
Vec::from(s);
```

However, this has to allocate memory not on the stack, then *copy* each value into that memory. It's more expensive than the other way, but might be the correct thing for a given situation.

> or vice versa

```
let v = vec![1u8, 2, 3];
let s = v.as_slice();
```

This is basically "free" as `v` still owns the data, we are just handing out a reference to it. That's why many APIs try to take slices when it makes sense.