# convert input vector of type &[T] to Vec<T>

Tags: pointers, rust

I am learning Rust by doing matrix math. The very first step is to create a new matrix of rows and columns, and initializes the matrix with the elements in values in row-major order.

If I want to pass the input matrix value vector as &[T], but I am not sure how to initialize the matrix with the elements values.

```
pub struct Matrix<T> {
    data: Vec<T>,
    row: usize,
    col: usize,
}

/// Creates a new matrix of `row` rows and `col` columns, and initializes
/// the matrix with the elements in `values` in row-major order.
pub fn new(row: usize, col: usize, values: &[T]) -> Matrix<T> {
    Matrix {
        data: *values, // ??
        row: row,
        col: col,
    }
}


fn main() {
    let x = Matrix::new(2, 3, &[-2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3]);
    let y = Matrix::new(2, 3, &[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]);
    // z = x + y;

}
```

Based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27554838/what-is-the-difference-between-vecstruct-and-struct) , &[T] is a reference to a set of Ts laid out sequentially in memory. Does that mean it is not possible to convert all the "slice" from pointers to vector type? And the only way to do is to use a loop to do deref of each item and store them in a new vector?

Comment: Personally, I would just make `new` accept a `Vec`. That way you don't impose a clone on the caller; the caller can decide to clone the data or just pass ownership of their `Vec` if they don't need it anymore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible, but not via `*` (dereferencing). You see, `&[T]` is something *borrowed*, so you can't keep it. The type `Matrix<T>` *owns* its `data`. You can't simply borrow something (`values`) and then give it away as if you own it ("here, Matrix, take these values, you can keep them").

What you can do is to copy the borrowed data and store it as an owned type (`Vec<T>`). You can now give away this copy of the data, because you own it. Converting from borrowed to owned can be done by the `to_owned()` method, for example:

```
pub fn new(row: usize, col: usize, values: &[T]) -> Matrix<T> {
    Matrix {
        data: values.to_owned(),
        //          ^^^^^^^^^^^
        row: row,
        col: col,
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Lukas, a follow up question: if by using to_own(), the fn new() takes the ownership of matrix , then the original matrix doesn't exist. If I want to do matrix addition, that would be a problem, right?  I am thinking maybe I should initialize the new matrix without taking the ownership..

Comment: @enaJ I don't quite understand, but the `new()` function doesn't take ownership of anything. `to_owned()` takes a *borrowed* thing, copies it and returns an *owned* thing. Like if a friend lends a book to you. You better not write into that book or pretend it's your own. But if you copy the book letter for letter, you have your own version that *you* own.

Comment: So to_owned() make a copy of the borrowed object. That makes sense. BTW, I really like your analogies.